# JPA query for select max(to_number(substr(reason_id,2,7))) from reason_type; No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.AggregateNode

Tags: jpa, max, substr

How we can write the following SQL query

```
select max(to_number(substr(reason_id,2,7)))
from reason_type;
```

In JPA for getting max row count for a column. I am trying it but I get an error when trying the following

```
Integer reasonTypeId = entityManager()
    .createQuery(
        "SELECT MAX(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(o.reasonId,2,7))) from ReasonType o",
         Integer.class)
    .getSingleResult();
```

My entity is `ReasonType` and column is reasonId.

Comment: Error which I am getting --No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.AggregateNode \-[AGGREGATE] AggregateNode: 'MAX' \-[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode: '(' +-[METHOD_NAME] IdentNode: 'TO_NUMBER' {originalText=TO_NUMBER} \-[EXPR_LIST] SqlNode: 'exprList' \-[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode: '(' +-[METHOD_NAME] IdentNode: 'SUBSTR' {originalText=SUBSTR} \-[EXPR_LIST] SqlNode: 'exprList' +-[DOT] DotNode: 'reasontype0_.REASON_ID' {:

Comment: I think Conversion of String to To_Number is creating issue..

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT MAX(TO_NUMBER('123'))` doesn't work, you need to use `SELECT MAX(CAST('123', integer))`.

`TO_NUMBER` is not Hibernate function, you need to use SQL's `CAST` instead